# pd.read_excel working in Jupyter but not in pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

When I am trying to read an excel file in Jupyter notebook its working fine. Whereas the same command is showing an error in Pycharm. I am using a Windows machine.

```
pd.read_excel(r"D:\dataBase\AttributeDataSet.xlsx")
```

The error popping up in pycharm is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
> raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.

I have also installed 'OpenPyxl' in Pycharm and tried the below code, but the same error persists.

```
pd.read_excel(r"D:\dataBase\AttributeDataSet.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl')
```

Please provide some suggestion to overcome this.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same Python interpreter or virtual environment in both programs.

Comment: Thnak you! Its working, now.